# Given a program, obtain a program that can operate on encrypted data

Tags: encryption

Suppose I have a program $P$. I would like to obtain an encryption function $e$, a decryption function $d$, and a program $Q$ such that $P(x) = d(Q(e(x)))$ for all inputs $x$. Ideally, the encryption would be asymmetric ($d$ cannot be obtained from $e$).

This would allow making a decentralized computing platform similar to Ethereum, but where contracts can store private data, only accessible by those with the decryption key.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: There are such things called homomorphic encryption schemes. You can check them out.

Comment: You would need to restrict what $P$ can do. Good luck if it's e.g. a program that outputs if $x$ is prime.

Comment: The requirement in question does look a lot like the correctness property of fully homomorphic encryption.

Comment: @SEJPM: Yes it _looks_ like a requirement for fully homomorphic encryption. But wouldn't FHE as we know it limit $P$ to be a polynomial function of $x$; and then in a particular finite field? For general-purpose program $P$, zk-SNARK comes to mind, but I'm uncomfortable with these, thus will not attempt an answer.

Comment: @fgrieu without having checked I'm 95% sure that you can formulate arbitrary (arithmetic) circuits with most FHE schemes (in the given field of course) which should allow you to formulate arbitrary computations (using a circuit) and not just polynomials.

Comment: @SEJPM: at some level of theory, there's no difference between "polynomial .. in a particular finite field" and "arbitrary (arithmetic) circuits.. in the given field". If the field has order $n$ it's easy to make a poly of degree $n-1$ that evaluates to 1 at a specified point, and to 0 at all others; and from that build a poly of degree $n-1$ for any function. So I agree with what you are 95% sure, both in theory, and in practice for small fields. But I have much doubt for practice and large field.  If the question gave an idea of what it wants to compute, that would help...